# Compiled query fails - Query was compiled for a different mapping source than the one associated with the specified DataContext

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have the following code for a compiled Linq2sql query to count rows in a table. The query throws an exception despite the same uncompiled query running smoothly:

```
public static Func<ServiceCustomContext, int> CompiledCount
    = CompiledQuery.Compile((ServiceCustomContext db) => db.Current.Count());
public static int Count()
{
    using (ServiceCustomContext db = new ServiceCustomContext(Constants.NewSqlConnection))
        return CompiledCount(db);
}
```

`ServiceCustomContext` inherits from `DataContext` and has only (besides a constructor) `Table`s including a table named `Current` used in the example above.

And I get the following exception:

> 'Query was compiled for a different mapping source than the one
>   associated with the specified DataContext.'

This is only when using, as above, a **compiled** query. As long as I have a simple:

```
return db.Current.Count();
```

in the `Count()` method, everything is fine.

I don't understand what's wrong. I thought it might be that I need to keep a reference to the DataContext (ServiceCustomContext) although that seemed counter intuitive, but even [the Microsoft examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities) don't do that. The only explanation I've found, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21223633/939213) which is basically that compiled queries as mentioned in the Microsoft examples in the link above are really wrong. I doubt that's true though.

Comment: Could it be because of the `ObjectTrackingEnabled` set to `false` ? What happens if it's set to `true` ?

Comment: @Fabjan Thanks. Didn't help. I now edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would run just fine if only you used `Count()` only once during the lifetime of your application. And the error means exactly what it says. If you look at the code of `CompiledQuery`:

```
    private object ExecuteQuery(DataContext context, object[] args) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("context");
        }
        if (this.compiled == null) {
            lock (this) {
                if (this.compiled == null) {
                    this.compiled = context.Provider.Compile(this.query);
                    this.mappingSource = context.Mapping.MappingSource;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (context.Mapping.MappingSource != this.mappingSource)
                throw Error.QueryWasCompiledForDifferentMappingSource();
        }
        return this.compiled.Execute(context.Provider, args).ReturnValue;
    }
```

You can see that what it does, it actually compiles the query only when it's first invoked. It also saves the reference to your `DataContext.Mapping.MappingSource` and makes sure you use the same `MappingSource` on every subsequent call.

By default, every time you create a new `DataContext`, a new `MappingSource` is created along. This is done in constructor and there is no way to override it later as both `DataContext.Mapping` and `MetaModel.MappingSource` properties only have a public getter. However, there is a constructor overload of `DataContext` which takes a `MappingSource` as an argument which (lucky you) allows you to reuse a single mapping source throughout the lifetime of your application.

Not sure what are the exact constructors of your `ServiceCustomContext` class, but the following code should give you a hint of the solution to prevent the error from happening:

```
public class ServiceCustomContext : DataContext
{
    private static readonly MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    public ServiceCustomContext(string connection) : base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
    }
}
```

I assumed you are using attributes for declaring mapping, however you can use `XmlMappingSource` in case you're using an XML file for your database mapping.